# Second scanner is ignoring input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have written Java code that has Scanners. What it is supposed to do is get 2 inputs and then do the math. The problem is that the second scanner doesn't work properly. It automatically does the else statement without asking for input.

```
package stuff;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Diagonal {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    double a = Math.pow(getHeight(), 2);
    System.out.println(a);
    double b = Math.pow(getWidth(), 2);
    double c = a + b;
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(c));


}

static double getWidth() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the width.");
    double width;
    if(scan.hasNextDouble()) {
        width = scan.nextDouble();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, there was an error!");
        width = 0;
    }
    scan.close();
    return width;
}

static double getHeight() {
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the height");
    double height;
    if(scan2.hasNextDouble()) {
        height = scan2.nextDouble();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, there was an error!");
        height = 0;
    }
    scan2.close();
    return height;
}

}
```

Comment: Hint: Use only one scanner and pass it to both the methods.

Comment: You are closing the input stream, which you can not do, if you expect to get more data from the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this:

```
double a = Math.pow(getHeight(), 2);
System.out.println(a);
double b = Math.pow(getWidth(), 2);
```

because getHeight() and getWidth() are methods that close the scanner, which is closing the System.in stream too...

so your 2 condition **scan.hasNextDouble()** is never met!

**Solution:**

use 1 scanner instance and close it when you are done reading inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can't reopen a standard input stream once you close it.  Your getHeight() method closes it so your getWidth() method cannot open it again.

Open a standard input stream once for your program and don't close it until you're done reading all user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reopen standard input stream once it is closed. so in our code remove Scanner objects from both methods and initialize it in the 'main' function once. like this and use the 'scan' object in both functions.

```
`static Scanner scan;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double a = Math.pow(getHeight(), 2);
        System.out.println(a);
        double b = Math.pow(getWidth(), 2);
        double c = a + b;
        System.out.println(Math.sqrt(c));
        scan.close();
    }`
```